# calling R user-defined functions from Perl

Tags: r, perl, function

Is there a way to call an R user-defined function from a Perl script?

I have looked at this module:

http://metacpan.org/pod/Statistics::R

And the examples it gives are of native R functions.

Is there a way to call afunction I defined?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

just define the function in the R call.
The trick is not to use "=" but "<-".
e.g.
$R->run(qq`ff<-function()"helloworld";ff()`);